# Convexity of the Domains of Affine Transformations

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Lately, I've been studying optimization and came across with the following problem formulation:

$$ \text{min} \;f_0(x) \\
\text{subject to} 
\begin{align}\;\;f_i(x) &≤ 0, \;\; i = 1, ..., m \\
\;\; h_i(x) &= 0, \;\;i = 1, ..., p\\
\end{align}  
$$
and the domain of the problem is defined to be

$$
D = \bigcap^m_{i=0} D_{f_i}  \cap \bigcap^p_{i=0} D_{h_i}
$$

Now, for a **convex optimization problem**, it is said that all $f_i$ must be convex and $h_i$ must be affine transformations. Then it suggests that the domain of the problem is convex since convex sets are closed under intersection.

If $f_i$ is convex, then $D_{f_i}$ is a convex set by definition. But what about affine transformations? Are the domains of affine transformations also convex by definition? Let's say I have an affine function $y = 3x + 2$ defined on $[-1, 2) \cup (3, 5]$. Domain is not convex, does it suggest that my function is not affine? If this is the case, can you please provide a reference to a reliable definition of affine functions?

For example for linear transformations, we can say that the definition implies convexity of the domain. Otherwise $T(\lambda  u +  (1 - \lambda) v) = \lambda T(u) +  (1 - \lambda) T(v)$ doesn't hold for all $u, v \in D_T$. Is there such a property of affine transformations we can use to achieve convexity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is affine if and only if
$$
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)
$$
for all $x,y$ in the domain of $f$ and $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

The domain of an affine function has to be a affine subspace, otherwise the definition makes no sense.
Affine subspaces are convex.

You can view it also differently: a function $f$ is affine iff $f$ and $-f$ are convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "the definition makes no sense" - Which definition are you referring to here? Can you write down a formal definition for affine transformations?